# How can I rebase and preserve merges and also do squash/fixup

Tags: git, rebase

When tasked with cleaning up a long running feature branch I find there are many commits in the history that needs to be squashed/fixed-up or reworded. I do want to keep the merges as they may have complicated conflict resolutions that I cannot do.

Imagine the following commits:

```
master: P0 - P1 - P2 - P3 --------------
         \    \                          \
feature:  A - M1 - B - C1 - C2 - C3 - D - M2 - E
```

Where `M`s are merges from the same branch (master)2.

And I want to fixup `C2` and `C3` into `C1` (and say reword `C1`).

When I do:
`git rebase -i -r master` I see all commits, and the merge, and I mark them with `f` and `r` as desired.

When this rebase is executed, and I reach the merge commit `M2`, git will complain with a conflict. I assume because it cannot apply the merge since commits were rewritten as a consequence of the fixups.

Is there a way to make git do such a merge without conflict? Given that I have not changed any lines of content will an `ours` or `theirs` always be correct in that case, and how would I do that in the middle of running this rebase.

Comment: Your merge has some other parent, that is not shown in your drawing. What is that other parent? (You are using the new `--rebase-merges`, aka `-r`, so that's good.)

Comment: With the older `--preserve-merges` I only get to modify the tail as it starts from the last merge. This is why I tried experimenting with `-r`.

Comment: I updated the post showing the parent and earlier merges from `master` into `feature`. There may have been merges into `feature` from yet another `subfeature` before I get to `M2` - in that case, that `subfeature` would be a branch from the closest `P` - for example from `P2` and merged after `B`.

Comment: *There may have been merges from yet another [branch]...* In that case I can see various ways how things might go wrong. A true reproducer ([mcve]) would help a lot.

Comment: ok, will try to reproduce with small example in a repo at github

Answer (score -1):

If in general terms, what you want to do is squash all your changes into a single one and rebase on top of the branch you started from.... I do it without all the rebase hassle like this:

```
git checkout my-branch
git merge the-target-branch
# finish that merge, doesn't matter the comment, it will go away
# when the merge is finished
git reset --soft the-target-branch
git commit -m "my squashed feature"
```

And you rebased/squashed without even noticing

Comment: I know I can squash everything. I am asking for a solution when I don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer eftshift0, there is nothing wrong with it, just not the solution I was asking for, so I am downvoting it.